# getting mod_perl working on a plain ubuntu 10.04 server install,

Tags: ubuntu, mod-perl

I am attempting to enable mod_perl on a fresh install of Lucid Lynx (ubuntu 10.04).

I have the libapache2-mod-perl2 installed, but I can't seem to get the .pl file to run instead of being downloaded.

-Perl 5.10.1

-Apache 2

I installed the "LAMP" configuration on install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mod_perl may not be what you are looking for.  Is the perl script designed to be run with mod_perl or is it a cgi script?

First, lets consider that it is a cgi script and not really meant to be run as mod_perl.  If that was the case, in your  block of your  config, you could put:

```
<Directory /path/to/webroot/>
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .pl
</Directory>
```

If the script had a proper #!/usr/bin/perl line at the top, and was able to be executed, apache should then serve it as a CGI script.

However, if you really do want to use mod_perl, you generally need to write a handler inside your VirtualHost config like:

```
<Location /virtualpath>
SetHandler modperl
PerlResponseHandler modulename::Function
</Location>
```

you might also need to put:

```
PerlRequire /path/to/startupscript.pl
```

to do your environment fixups.  Generally, mod_perl handlers are .pm files and are packages rather than .pl files.